# PHP/Wordpress: list posts per sub-category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, categories

In the below code there's a loop that features all products under a given category:

```
        <?php        

            wp_reset_query();
            query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=15&paged=' . $paged);
            if (have_posts()) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $price =  get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'inception_price', true);

        ?>

            <div class="omc-product-listing">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php 

                        if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        the_post_thumbnail('product', array('class' => 'omc-product-frame'));  
                        } else {
                    ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ;?>/images/no-image.png" width="170" height="170" class="omc-product-frame" alt="no photo" />

                    <?php } ?>

                </a>

                <span class="omc-listing-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></span>

                <span class="omc-listing-price"><?php echo($price);?></span>

                <span class="omc-listing-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">&raquo;</a></span>

            </div><!-- /omc-product-listing -->

        <?php endwhile;  ?>

        <br class="clear" /> 

        <div class="product-pagination">

            <?php  kriesi_pagination(); ?>    

        </div>                        

        <br class="clear" /> 

        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

In this loop, I'd like to pull out every product for a given category (that's what the code does now), but display then "per subcategory", like this:

For category publications:

Books:

- Book 33
- Book 32
- Book 1
- ...

Mobile Apps:

- App 12
- App 76
- ...

...

I think the code above needs a `foreach` loop, like below, but I don't know how to implement it in this case.

```
            <?php
            // get all the categories from the database
            $cats = get_categories();

                // loop through the categories
                foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                    // setup the categories ID
                    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
                    // Make a header for the categories
                    echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
                    // create a custom wordpress query
                    query_posts("cat=$cat_id&post_per_page=100");
                    // start the wordpress loop!
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                    <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
                <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken this request to wpquestions.com. It just got resolved by Abdessamad Idrissi. the answer is too long to copy it here, so I'm posting the [discussion link](http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/3140) and the [code link](http://pastebin.com/cb5e9egt) here, in case someone has the same need.

Comment: +1 for your self learning and providing link for others. Keep on going.

Comment: Thanks Awais, appreciate it. Last version of the code [here](http://pastebin.com/cb5e9egt).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$cats = get_categories();

foreach ($cats as $cat) :

// setup the categories ID
 $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
// Make a header for the categories
echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";

$args = array( 'cat' => $cat_id, 'posts_per_page' => 100 );

$posts = get_posts($args);

if($posts) :

foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endforeach; // foreach($posts)

endif; // if($posts)

endforeach; // foreach($cats)
```

Not tested this but it should put you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks Dave, see my comments bellow. Cheers.